# yii2 leftjoin query builder

Tags: php, yii2, query-builder

I have a relation/hierarchy between User and Staff: a Staff is always an User but an User can also be a Student or an Admin. Now, through a query I want to get just the staff records that has is_disabled field in User equals to false. I tried with the following but gives me the error:

> staff hasn't is_disabled field

That is true, that field is only in User table.

User

```
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string password
```

Staff

```
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $cellphone
 * @property string $phone
 * @property string $link
 * @property User $id0
```

SearchStaff

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Staff::find()
    ->leftJoin('user', '`user`.`id` = `staff`.`id`')
    ->where(['user.is_disabled' => false);
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are getting this error on these exact lines? i dont think so

Comment: what error did you get? please report error

Comment: @gipsy have some patience for someone trying to help you out by sparing from his personal time, maybe he wasnt able to see the mentioned error, you could have said that politely, Happy SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join is wrong, the foreign key should be `id0`.

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Staff::find()
    ->leftJoin('user', 'user.id = staff.id0')
    ->where(['user.is_disabled' => false);
}
```

You can also create a relation in Staff model:

```
public function getUser(){
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'id0']);
}
```

And edit the query:

```
$query = Staff::find()
  ->joinWith('user')
  ->where(['user.is_disabled' => false)];
```

Comment: ahh i didnt catch that when i saw the query the first time, good catch., and i just updated your code for the `leftJoin()` the reason for the error @gipsy was having